# HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error when get Image in ASP.net web API folder

Tags: asp.net-web-api, web-config, iis-10, http-status-code-500, ntfs-mft

I am trying to browse Image from Images folder in my ASP.net web API project like this:- http://localhost:56951/Images/221020065254AM_13906734_658826644282707_5299628712403615086_n.jpg[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfdiR.jpg). I have got the Image name and extension from DB and I call for Image Using this Url, I have Called many times before but  unfortunately, at this time I got HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error

Comment: How big are the images? `0x800703e9` means stack overflow.

Comment: just 51.2 KB @LexLi Li

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps to solve the problem.

1. Be sure you have .NET Extensibility Feature installed on server.

- windows features > Internet Information Services > world wide web services >
  Application development Features > Choose .NET Extensibility and install

[image]

2.Be sure you have modules added in system.server

```
 <system.webServer>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <add name="UrlRewrite" type="Rewriteurl.urlrewrite"/>
   </modules>
 <system.webServer>
```